# unzip: can't set permissions of directory 'folder' : Invalid argument

Tags: zip, gunzip

I have the below script to unzip a .zip file and print out a .txt file of the files in the .zip but when I run the script, I get this output:
"unzip: can't set permissions of directory 'folder' : Invalid argument"

My script:

```
for file in *.zip
do
    unzip -- "$file"
    [ -d "${file%%.zip}" ]
    cd "${file%%.zip}"
    echo -e "${file}\t$(echo $(gzip -cd ${file}|wc -l)/4|bc)" >> results.txt
done
```

Comment: Usual reason is you are doing it on a system where permissions are meaningless, such as exfat.

Comment: What's the output of `df -T`?